# Finding parameter so Newton Method converges cubically

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Consider the function $\phi(x)=x^b(x^2-a)$. Find a value for $b\neq 0$ independent of $a$ so that the Newton Interative Method for $\phi$ locally converges cubically to $\sqrt{a}$.

I know that for local cubic converges of the Newton method I need to have $\phi''(x^*)=0$ where $x^*$ is the fix point we are looking for.

When I calculate the second derivative I get this;
$$\phi''(x)=b^2x^b+3bx^b+2x^b-b^2ax^{b-2}+bax^{b-2}$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like you just need to plug in $\sqrt{a}$ for $x$ and solve for $\phi''(\sqrt{a})=0$.

Comment: It'll still be one equation. I need $b$ as a parameter to be independant of $a$

Comment: Your problem statement is not worded that way. Moreover, I would think $b$ would depend on $a$ in general.

Comment: I fixed it; the method is a modified method of the Babylonian iteration to find $\sqrt{a}$

Comment: In general the cubically convergent Halley method can be obtained as the Newton method for $\phi(x)=f(x)/\sqrt{|f'(x)|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set $\phi''(\sqrt{a}\,)=0$ using these steps:
\begin{align*}
\phi(x)&=x^{b+2}-a x^b\\
\phi'(x)&=(b+2)\,x^{b+1}-ab\,x^{b-1}\\
\phi''(x)&=(b+1)(b+2)\,x^b-ab(b-1)\,x^{b-2}\\
\phi''(\sqrt{a}\,)&=(b+1)(b+2)\,a^{b/2}-ab(b-1)\,a^{b/2-1}\overset{\text{set}}{=}0.
\end{align*}
The $a^{b/2}$ factor is never zero, so we eliminate it to obtain
$$0=(b+1)(b+2)-ab(b-1)a^{-1}=b^2+3b+2-b^2+b=4b+2,$$
with solution
$$b=-\frac12.$$